# Finding matrix of oblique projector

Tags: matrices, projection, projection-matrices

> Find a matrix of oblique projector in $\Bbb R^3$ onto the subspace $U =ls\{(1,0,1)^T\}$ parallel to the subspace $W = ls\{(1,1,0)^T, (0,1,1)^T\}$.

---

How I should find this oblique projector matrix in the following task? Information at Wikipedia seems to be a little bit complicated and I haven`t found any practical examples for oblique projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS: “onto the subspace $U$” means that the projector is the identity map on $U$, while “parallel to the subspace $W$” means that $W$ is the kernel of the projector. Construct a simple matrix that has the requisite rank and apply a change of basis to it.